# Android studio create buildSrc but in build.gradle.kts implementation no found

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-dsl, buildsrc

gradle version

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

buildSrc/src/build.gradle.kts

```
plugins{
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
}
dependencies {
    implementation(rootProject.extra["androidPlugin"].toString())
    implementation(rootProject.extra["kotlinPlugin"].toString())
}
```

but  `implementation`    no found

i clone github coil project  it can run and  can found implementation

i want help

Comment: I think `File>Invalidate Caches and Restart` should fix it. Or just clean the project and rebuild

Comment: import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.kotlin
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.project      all no foud

Comment: @gtxtreme  Tried it and it didn't work

Comment: Any news on this issue?